# LINQ Select in descending order from collection, three different values that go up to the maximum value of the element

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections

For example i have a collection like this

```
var c1 = new Collection<int>{0,0,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,7};
```

I would like to get result like this

```
(6,5,4)
```

Comment: Why 6, 5 ,4? Why not 7, 6, 5?

Comment: Select in descending order from collection, three different values that go UP  to the maximum value of the element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
c1.Distinct()
    .OrderByDescending(x => x)
    .Skip(1)
    .Take(3)
    .ToList()
```

First remove all the duplicates, then sort despondingly. `Skip(1)` so that the max element is removed. Finally you can take 3 elements from the rest.

Answer (score 1):

In the old days, before LINQ, we might have done this on a sorted collection like you have:

```
var maxes = new int[4];
var idx = 0;
var max = 0;
foreach(var c in c1)
  if(c > max)
    max = maxes[(idx++)%4] = c;
```

At the end of this you'll have an array with 4 max values - the 3 you want, and the one you don't (which is in `(idx - 1) % 4`). I don't know if I'd use it now, but it's more efficient than a "distinct, then sort, then skip then take" approach as it does its work in a single pass